# weblogic.appc command failed using ANT script in WebLogic Server 10.3.5.0

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am migrating an application from weblogic 8.1 to weblogic 10.3.5 version. 
while building application through ant script; I am getting below error:-

weblogic.appc.run:

```
[java] Usage: java weblogic.appc [options] <ear, jar, war or rar file or directory> 
[java] 
[java] where options include: 
[java] -help Print the standard usage message. 
[java] -version Print version information. 
[java] -output <file> Specifies an alternate output archive or 
[java] directory. If not set, output will be 
[java] placed in the source archive or directory. 
[java] -plan <file> Specifies an optional deployment plan. 
[java] -forceGeneration Force generation of EJB and JSP classes. 
[java] Without this flag the classes may not be 
[java] regenerated if it is determined to be 
[java] unnecessary. 
[java] -quiet Turns off output except for errors 
[java] -lineNumbers Add JSP line numbers to generated class 
[java] files to aid in debugging. 
[java] -library <file> Comma-separated list of libraries. Each 
[java] library may optionally set its name and 
[java] versions, if not already set in its 
[java] manifest, using the following syntax: <file> 
[java] [@name=<string>@libspecver=<version> 
[java] @libimplver=<version|string>] 
[java] -librarydir <dir> Registers all files in specified directory 
[java] as libraries. 
[java] -writeInferredDescriptors Write out the descriptors with inferred 
[java] information including annotations. 
[java] -manifest <file> Include manifest information from specified 
[java] manifest file. 
[java] -clientJarOutputDir <dir> Specifies a directory to put generated 
[java] client jars. 
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/j2ee/J2EELogger 
[java] -keepgenerated Keep the generated .java files. 
[java] -verbose Compile with verbose output. 
[java] -classpath <path> Classpath to use. 
[java] -source <source> Source version. 
[java] -target <target> Target version. 
[java] -advanced Print advanced usage options. 
[java] 
[java] at weblogic.application.compiler.Appc.runBody(Appc.java:205) 
[java] at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158) 
[java] at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115) 
[java] at weblogic.application.compiler.Appc.main(Appc.java:262) 
[java] at weblogic.appc.main(appc.java:14) 
[java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.j2ee.J2EELogger 
[java] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) 
[java] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
[java] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) 
[java] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) 
[java] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) 
[java] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) 
[java] ... 5 more
```

Below are ANT script which I am running over it.

```
<java classname="weblogic.appc" failonerror="true" fork="true" maxmemory="512m"> 
  <arg value="-disableHotCodeGen"/>
  <arg line="-verbose"/>
  <arg line="${weblogic.arg.line.compiler}"/>
  <arg line="-compilerclass com.sun.tools.javac.Main"/>
  <arg line="${weblogic.appc.options}"/>
  <arg value="${compile.dir}/${ejb.domain}-ejbc.jar"/>
  <arg value="${project.dir}/src/java"/>
  <arg value="${compile.dir}/ejb/${ejb.domain}"/>
  <classpath>
    <path refid="weblogic.classpath"/>
    <path refid="project.classpath"/>
    <fileset dir="${java.home}/../lib" includes="tools.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</java>
```

Even though I am not able to find java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/j2ee/J2EELogger . which jar does supports this? Also I have set PATH and CLASSPATH properly.

Let me know if more information is required from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, ensure you have `/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar` in your `weblogic.classpath` variable.

The class that isn't loading is from `/modules/com.oracle.core.weblogic.msgcat_1.1.0.0.jar`. This should be imported by virtue of the MANIFEST.MF file in `/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar`. Assuming that you have weblogic.jar in your `weblogic.classpath` then the class `weblogic.j2ee.J2EELogger` should be loaded.

`weblogic.jar` loads `/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.5.0.jar` which in turn through it's own MANIFEST.MF loads `/modules/com.oracle.core.weblogic.msgcat_1.1.0.0.jar`.

You also have multiple `<arg line="">` tags in your ant configuration. You will need to revise these.

```
<arg line="-disableHotCodeGen -verbose -compilerclass com.sun.tools.javac.Main ${weblogic.appc.options} ${compile.dir}/${ejb.domain}-ejbc.jar ${project.dir}/src/java ${compile.dir}/ejb/${ejb.domain}">
```

Another example below is how I currently execute appc in my ant build.

```
<target name="appc" depends="compile,jar">
  <java classname="weblogic.appc" fork="yes" jvm="${bea.java.home}/bin/java" maxmemory="1G" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="${archive.jarfile} -J-Xmx1g"/>
    <classpath>
      <pathelement path="${container.cp};${server.additional.classpath}"/>
      <pathelement path="${archive.jarfile}"/>
    </classpath>
  </java>
</target>
```

Also, run ant with the `-v` switch to see the command being issued, it should help to find your problem.

Comment: Thanks!!! weblogic.j2ee.J2EELogger found on below jars com.bea.core.logging_1.8.0.0.jar and com.oracle.core.weblogic.msgcat_1.1.0.0.jar.but after this I got another below build issue.  [java] <Sep 13, 2012 6:11:47 PM IST> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160187> <weblogic.appc failed to compile your application. Recompile with the -verbose option for more details. 
 Please see the error message(s) below.>
 [java] [J2EE:160128]ERROR: Incorrect appc command-line. 
 Too many arguments were given. The command-line only takes a single argument, the source file, 
 in addition to the supported options.

Comment: Yes, I see that now too. Put all the program arguments into a single <arg line="-disableHotCodeGen -verbose -compilerclass com.sun.tools.javac.Main ${weblogic.appc.options} ${compile.dir}/${ejb.domain}-ejbc.jar ${project.dir}/src/java ${compile.dir}/ejb/${ejb.domain}">

Comment: Hi, I tried single arg as specified by you but I still got the same error while using appc compiler : [J2EE:160128]ERROR: Incorrect appc command-line. Too many arguments were given. The command-line only takes a single argument, the source file, in addition to the supported options.

Comment: I've added an example of a working appc command in Ant that I use in my existing build.